# When is the power-bounded subring top. of finite type?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, p-adic-analysis, rigid-analytic-geometry

Very naive question here. Let $K$ be a complete nonarchimedean field, $A$ a reduced affinoid $K$-algebra. When is the power-bounded subring $A^\circ$ topologically of finite type, in the sense that we can find a surjection $\mathcal{O}_K \left\langle X_1,\dots,X_n \right\rangle \twoheadrightarrow A^\circ$? The answer is "always" if $K$ is discretely valued, or $K$ is stable and the value group $|K^\ast|$ is divisible (in particular if $K$ is algebraically closed). This follows from some stuff in sections 6.3-6.4 of Bosch-Guntzer-Remmert, which in fact proves much more.

Surely the answer is not "always", but I'm having an annoyingly difficult time constructing a counterexample. I suspect that if $p>2$ and $K=\widehat{\mathbf{Q}_p(p^{1/p^\infty})}$, the power-bounded subring of $A= K \left\langle X,\frac{X^2}{p} \right\rangle$ is not topologically of finite type, but I wasn't quite able to prove it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was being silly. Corollary 6.4.3/6 in BGR implies that for $K$ NOT discretely valued, $A^\circ$ is top. finite type iff there exists a distinguished surjection $\alpha: K \left\langle X_1,\dots,X_n \right\rangle \twoheadrightarrow A$, i.e. a surjection such that the sup norm $|\cdot|_{sup}$ on $A$ coincides with the residue norm $|\cdot|_\alpha$. But the existence of a distinguished surjection implies that $|A|_{sup} = |K|$, so any $A$ with $|A|_{sup} \supsetneq |K|$ gives a counterexample. In particular, the ring I wrote down is a counterexample indeed, because $|X|_{\sup}=p^{-1/2} \notin |K|$.